# State variable changes not called by Firebase sync Request , SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, synchronization, state

I keep a firebase request sync to retrieve value from db (value changed by BackEnd) .

When the value changes , firebase request called , count value is changed but onChange is not called (due to the fact that swift compares references ?) . Here is the code with an OO . It doesn make sense from a swiftui point of view but this is just to show that view  isn t sync when using Firebase sync request (value is)

```
class GlobalOO: ObservableObject {
    @Published var  multiV :String = "0"
}

import SwiftUI
import Firebase



private var multiSelectQuery : DatabaseReference!
private var handle :DatabaseHandle!



struct SearchToolBar: View {


@ObservedObject var globalOO = GlobalOO()



var body: some View {
    
    
    Text(globalOO.multiV)
        
        .onReceive(globalOO.$multiV, perform: { _ in
            
            print("received")
            
        })
        
        
        .onAppear{
          
              //this pat is only to update value in the db
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3){
                Global.myRef.child(Strings.dbname_states).setValue("5")
                
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+6){
                Global.myRef.child(Strings.dbname_states).setValue("7")
                
            }
            
           //
            
            multiSelection()
        }
    
    
    
}

private func multiSelection(){
    
    multiSelectQuery = Global.myRef.child(Strings.dbname_states)
    multiSelectQuery.keepSynced(true)
    
    handle =   multiSelectQuery.observe(.value,with :{(snapshot) in
        
        let multiValue:String = snapshot.value! as! String
        
        globalOO.multiV = multiValue

        print("DDD",globalOO.multiV)
        
    })
    
    
    
}


}
```

Comment: Where is `snapshot` ?

Comment: Here thank you for the remark . Since it is based on a firebase request , hence not easilty reproducible , i didn t include it . Facts : Quey.keepSynced(true) . facts : count value updates when value in db changes .

Comment: Networking calls should probably not be done in the View, but rather in an ObservableObject

Comment: Thank you jnpdx . At this moment , i ve managed to getupdates from the request using an OO . However, even if onReceive is called;Assigning the value from the OO to count (state var) doesn t update the view at all (onChange still not called) and  view not udpated . It is difficult because at one point value has to be assigned to count for the view to be updated . By hand (onTap) , no issue

Comment: and furthermore, onReceive is really called when it feels to , not reliable so far

Comment: You shouldn't be assigning from the ObservableObject to `@State` -- use a `@Published` property on the ObservableObject.

Comment: Thank you . I removed State var from the process  However, onReceive works (sometimes) but even when it works, Text can display the initial value of the OO but doesn t get updated even if the OO value is . (I tried with and without onReceive, i tried to change id-nothing works) .

Comment: You'd need to come up with a [mre] showing that. In my experience, `@Published` values  are always reflected in the observing view hierarchy.

Comment: i will update the question with more code, thank you

Comment: this is just to show that value is updated with firebase request . I guess that any sync request with a value as a string (not a dic) should be ok to reproduce

Comment: But if I make your `multiSelection` something that just updates the OO after a certain amount of time (`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { globalOO.multiV = "Test" }`), it works fine -- `onReceive` is called and the `Text` updates. Which means there's something else going on in your code and it doesn't have to do with `onReceive` or `@Published` variables...

Comment: I m not sure if i understood correctly but yes , without Firebase requests it udpates .With ; it doesnt . Value of the OO is updated but not view . I did with this code and nothing more . So , i m not sure if i get it but it can be reproduced only with a sync Firebase request. I tried with state, OO , serval conditions, several possibilities but the view never got updated . There s nothing more running than this code  (and i havea decent firebase experience)

Comment: If i pass the value retrieved by firebase with @Binding to another view, view gets updated ; in the given example , with OO or State , view isn t updated. Even with delays or anything , from Firebase , in the same view , no update . This is beyond my limited swift knowledge

Comment: What happens if you explicitly wrap the update in `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`?

Comment: I tried it :Upon value change , i can retrieve the value for @State or OO . I can get it straight or postpone . OnReceive can be called (or not with the same code) but view will never be updated , with or without delays,direclty or thru undirect ways.

Comment: With no code change , the same click can trigger onReceive and after rebuild by xcode, it is not called anymore